# order email is BCC to previous customer

Tags: magento-1.9, email

weird bug - when we get a new order in Magento - the system sends an email to them but also sends a BCC to a previous customer?
This is slightly weird! Any idea why?

Also the shipment confirmation email doesnt go to customer...

Comment: Does it bcc to the same previous customer or to the customer from the previous order before this one? Also are you using any third party to send email?

Comment: hi there - no its random! can be previous customer a few orders back, no third party but we have cron job enabled

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a bug where it's only sent to customers who's order is still Processing. It doesn't send to the previous customer if the order is already marked complete/shipped.

Updating to 1.9.2.1 resolved the problem entirely for me but I'm unsure as to the exact change.